# WIN32_PROCESS class for Powershell command Get-WmiObject

Tags: command-line, powershell, java

I hope this question is not too simple for this forum, so thanks in advance for treating it nicely.

I was trying to do some small exercise regarding the following:

1. Enquire via PowerShell about a java process that I am interested in
2. Grab the PID
3. Use it in my Java application.

My Java is 64-bit.

What I did was the following:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -List "name = 'java.exe' and commandline like '%catalina%'
```

Even if my java process is 64-bit, the WQL query is looking for the data into win32_process (and retrieves from there successfully). Is this actually by design or am I looking at wrong things here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The WQL query is looking for the data into win32_process

> The Win32_Process WMI class represents a process on an operating system.

Source [Win32_Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Win32_Process just happens to be the name of the class, it returns all processes whether they are 32 or 64 bit.

If you need to find out whether a process is 32 or 64 bit refer to this Stack Overflow question [Powershell: Determine if a process is 32 or 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23024659/3536342).